# Custom oAuth system with back4app

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, back4app

I want to develop an app mobile (in Flutter) with a cloud backend (I have not another server).
With Firebase, it supports only 4 providers (Fb, Twitter, Google, Github).

I need to connect Strava oAuth and use this login in my backend service. So, back4app is perhaps the solution.
Here, listing of providers supported by back4app https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#oauth-and-3rd-party-authentication, but no Strava...

Another section here to use non supported provider : https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#custom-authentication but how can I do ? I don't understand this section.

Thxs

Comment: You can write your own custom oauth adapter at Back4App. Please reach out the team in the web-site chat. They will be glad to help you to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I've used Firebase with a external server ;)